# How to retain customer login after switching website in Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, customer-session, multi-website, switcher

I have a **website switcher** button on my **Magento 2.3** site *(not a store switcher)*.

When a customer logs in on the website - **abc.magento.com**, I programmatically switch the website to **pqr.magento.com**, it redirects to the new website but logs out my customer.

I tried setting "YES" for following Configuration Setting

> General -> Web -> Session Validation Settings -> Used SID on
>   storefront

But it didn't work.

Is there any way to prevent logging out and maintain the customer session.

Comment: First check this Stores --> Configuration --> Customers --> Customer Configuration: and set to Global

Comment: It has already been set to Global, but still customer logs out

Comment: same issue for me,I have set to Global still its asking to login again. Anyone have any idea regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently, I found a solution based on the native : `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher` and I have build the following controller, it create an url like : https://mysite1.local/store/change/?code=mysite2 and it keep the connexion if the customer was logged in the first site and if the customer accounts are shared between website.

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Store\Controller\Change;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\ViewModel\SwitcherUrlProvider;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $switcherUrlProvider;
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        SwitcherUrlProvider $switcherUrlProvider,
        EncoderInterface $encoder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->switcherUrlProvider = $switcherUrlProvider;
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $code = $this->getRequest()->getParam('code');
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($code);
        $url = $this->_url->getUrl(
           'stores/store/redirect',
           [
                '___store' => $store->getCode(),
                '___from_store' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getCode(),
                ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED => $this->encoder->encode(
                    $store->getUrl('customer/account/login')
                ),
            ]
        );
        return $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT)->setUrl($url);
    }
}
```